# Python run shell command and emulate user input

Tags: python, shell, emulation

How can i from a python script emulate user data like:

Say i run os.system('grunt init:gruntfile'), and i want the python script automatically to 'enter'  some data, so instead of the user inputs the data that the shell command asks for, the python script enters some data hard-coded in the script?

Hope my question makes sense and that someone can help.
Thank you in advance, adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pexpect`](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) will probably fit your bill if plain old `subprocess` doesn't.

From the `pexpect` site:

> For example::
>
> ```
> child = pexpect.spawn('scp foo myname@host.example.com:.')
> child.expect ('Password:')
> child.sendline (mypassword)
> ```

Comment: Can i get the output of the shellcommand in the python console?